# in Python3/tkinter is it possible to create a toolbar into a separate class, but still allowing it to interact with the main app?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter, toolbar

I am about to begin a new Python3/tkinter project and I want to make sure that I get as much code out of my way as possible. I am creating an app that will have, for now, one window composed of 3 areas:

- Toolbar
- Center/main area
- Statusbar

I am trying to keep the main app class as clean as possible, offloading code to other auxiliary classes. So, following some tutorials and adapting from what I have been doing until now, I was able already to set an external toolbar class that can be changed on demand, from the main app. Now, I am trying to create a class for the toolbar, but I am afraid it won't be possible to create the buttons and their respective callbacks in a separate class, as I don't know how to make them call functions that are in the main app. Is that even possible?

This is what I got right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App:
    """ main class for the application """
    def __init__(self,master):
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(master)
        topframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        centerframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        bottomframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe)

        my_toolbar = Toolbar(topframe) 

        my_statusbar = StatusBar(mainframe)
        my_statusbar.set("This is the statusbar")

        centerlabel = ttk.Label(centerframe, text="Center stuff goes here")
        centerlabel.pack()

        topframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        centerframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)        
        mainframe.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


    def button_function(self, *event):
        print("filter")


class StatusBar(ttk.Frame):
    """ Simple Status Bar class - based on Frame """
    def __init__(self,master): 
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.label = ttk.Label(self,anchor=W)
        self.label.pack()
        self.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def set(self,texto):
        self.label.config(text=texto)
        self.label.update_idletasks()
    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()


class Toolbar:
    """ Toolbar """
    def button_one(self):
        print("button 1 pressed")

    def button_two(self):
        print("button 2 pressed")

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(master,text="One",command=self.button_one())
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(master,text="Two",command=self.button_two())
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = Tk() 
    app = App(root) 
    root.mainloop()
```

Let's say that I need to make `button1` to trigger `button_function()` in order to update some info being shown there. Should I simply move the toolbar into the `App` class, for instance in a class method called from its `__init__()`? Or is there a better way?

Maybe I should add that i intend later to add some `Toplevel`windows that probably could make use of some of these general classes. I want to pave the road in a nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible. There are two possibilities here. The first one to make app inherit from ttk.Frame instead of using mainframe. Then you can pass App as master to toolbar etc. Here is the redone code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):
    """ main class for the application """
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)


        self.my_toolbar = Toolbar(self) 

        self.my_statusbar = StatusBar(self)
        self.my_statusbar.set("This is the statusbar")

        self.centerframe = CenterFrame(self)

        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


    def button_function(self, *event):
        print("filter")


class CenterFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.centerlabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Center stuff goes here")
        self.centerlabel.pack()


class StatusBar(ttk.Frame):
    """ Simple Status Bar class - based on Frame """
    def __init__(self,master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.label = ttk.Label(self,anchor=tk.W)
        self.label.pack()
        self.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    def set(self,texto):
        self.label.config(text=texto)
        self.label.update_idletasks()
    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()


class Toolbar(ttk.Frame):
    """ Toolbar """
    def button_one(self):
        print("button 1 pressed")

    def button_two(self):
        print("button 2 pressed")
        self.master.button_function()

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="One",command=self.button_one)
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self,text="Two",command=self.button_two)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = App(root) 
    root.mainloop()
```

The second one is to just pass App as an argument to the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some `self.`, button commands assignments don't need parenthesis and after that you can call the button configuration from anywhere in your program. So for the button1 command this will be:

```
app.my_toolbar.button1.config(command=app.button_function)
```

I am fixing your errors as is, not make the program better:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App:
    """ main class for the application """
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        self.centerframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        self.bottomframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)

        self.my_toolbar = Toolbar(self.topframe)

        self.my_statusbar = StatusBar(self.mainframe)
        self.my_statusbar.set("This is the statusbar")

        self.centerlabel = ttk.Label(self.centerframe, text="Center stuff goes here")
        self.centerlabel.pack()

        self.topframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.centerframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


    def button_function(self, *event):
        print("filter")


class StatusBar(ttk.Frame):
    """ Simple Status Bar class - based on Frame """
    def __init__(self,master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.label = ttk.Label(self,anchor=W)
        self.label.pack()
        self.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def set(self,texto):
        self.label.config(text=texto)
        self.label.update_idletasks()
    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()


class Toolbar:
    """ Toolbar """
    def button_one(self):
        print("button 1 pressed")

    def button_two(self):
        print("button 2 pressed")

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(master,text="One",command=self.button_one)
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(master,text="Two",command=self.button_two)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)

    app.my_toolbar.button1.config(command=app.button_function)

    root.mainloop()
```