# Call method class from other method class in Python Ptinker

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I´m creating GUI with Python and Tkinter, its actually awesome and I decided to use classes to have the code more readable, but we have an issue, the GUI (App) have two menus (***LeftMenu and RightMenu***) created with a common parent (***MainGrid***), my goal is click "**Run**" button from LeftMenu and call method ***call_text_area*** inside RightMenu
and perform operation with this method and elements related to the class ***RightMenu***

When I click "**Run**" button  the terminal show the following:

```
  File "<route>/mainV4.py", line 78, in clicked
self.master.button_function()
```

AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'button_function'

Actually I follow the instruction from this url [in Python3/tkinter is it possible to create a toolbar into a separate class, but still allowing it to interact with the main app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381385/in-python3-tkinter-is-it-possible-to-create-a-toolbar-into-a-separate-class-but), but it just to call parent method from the child class it works very well, but how can I call ***call_text_area*** method that is on the same level as another class ?

This is py file

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
from config import config as configProp

class App(Frame):
    """ main class for the application """

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.set_dimension(master)

        self.center_frame = MainGrid(self)

        self.center_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    def set_dimension(self, master):
        print("set dimension")

        master.maxsize(configProp.width, configProp.heigth)
        master.geometry(configProp.defaultSize)
        master.title(configProp.name_project)
        master.config(bg="skyblue")


class MainGrid(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        print("create main grid")

        self.left_frame = Frame(master, width=50, height=400, bg='blue')
        self.left_frame.pack(side='left', fill='both', padx=1, pady=5, expand=False)

        self.right_frame = Frame(master, width=850, height=400, bg='blue')
        self.right_frame.pack(side='right', fill='both', padx=10, pady=5, expand=True)

        self.create_left_menu(self.left_frame)
        self.create_rigth_menu(self.right_frame)

    def create_left_menu(self, parent):
        LeftMenu(parent)

    def create_rigth_menu(self, parent):
        RightMenu(parent)

class LeftMenu(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)



        self.master = master
        self.config( bg="skyblue")

        self.tool_bar = Frame(master, width=20, height=185, bg='grey')
        self.tool_bar.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=5)

        # Example labels that serve as placeholders for other widgets
        Label(self.tool_bar, text="Tools", relief=RAISED).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=30, ipadx=10)

        # For now, when the buttons are clicked, they only call the clicked() method. We will add functionality later.
        Button(self.tool_bar, text="Select file", command=self.clicked).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5,
                                                                             sticky='w' + 'e' + 'n' + 's')
        Button(self.tool_bar, text="Run", command=self.clicked).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5,
                                                                     sticky='w' + 'e' + 'n' + 's')

    def clicked(self):
        self.master.call_text_area()
        print("Tkinter is easy to use!")

    def send_data(self, *event):
        pass

class RightMenu(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.information = ["one", "two"]
        print("create right menu")

        self.tabControl = Notebook(master)

        tab1 = Frame(self.tabControl)
        tab2 = Frame(self.tabControl)

        text_areaOutput = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tab1, wrap=WORD, width=40, height=8,
                                                    font=("Times New Roman", 15))
        text_areaOutput.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
        self.tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    def call_text_area(self):
        print('hello')
        for x in self.information:
            print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

I really appreciate any help

Comment: terminology note: none of those are "class methods". They are all instance methods, or just "method" for short.

Comment: And I don't know tkinter,  but there is no `button_function` defined anywhere.

Comment: ohh tank you so much @juanpa.arrivillaga, I´ve already corrected the question, it´s call_text_area instead of button_function

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are calling `self.master.button_function()` in line 78, which is blank in the code you provided. You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: But anyway, and again, I don't know tkinter, but you create `LeftMenu(parent)`, where `parent` will be assigned to `self.master` in `LeftMenu`. And then you try to call `self.master.call_text_area()`, but `master` is just a regular  `Frame` object, `self.left_frame = Frame(master, width=50, height=400, bg='blue')`

Comment: I don't understand why you create `self.left_frame` and `self.right_frame` as children of the *parent of `MainGrid`* instead of *`MainGrid` itself*.